Set Static IP Addresses on Harvester
I have a Harvester cluster. I want to create 3 VMs. The VMs will be part of a Kubernetes cluster.
For this, the VMs need constant IPs, which causes issues with the mgmt cluster network which insists on giving a new IP to VMs on restart.
Currently, I do the following:

Set node specs
Choose VM image (openSUSE)
Set network options (use bridge, not masquerade)
Add cloud config for static IP.

However, when the VM is created, it is still assigned an IP by harvester.
Cloud Config:
network:
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets:
        - type: static
          address: 192.168.23.14/27
          gateway: 192.168.23.1
          dns_nameservers:
            - 8.8.8.8

Harvester will nonetheless provide another IP address to the VM, and the VM will not be accessible on either of the 2 IPs.
If it's relevant, I installed the harvester-vm-dhcp-controller addon for allocating IPs in my LAN to VMs in Harvester. However, the issue persists whether the addon is enabled or not.
I have also created VM networks, both DHCP and manual, but there is no change.

This appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/harvester/harvester/issues/5452
Furthermore, this should be able to be resolved for a DHCP on/off setting for each VM: https://github.com/harvester/harvester/issues/5052
